# How to extract video+audio streams from MP4 file via ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gopro

I have a bunch of MP4 files from a GoPro, which include streams of metadata like GPS information. Now unfortunately when I try to open these MP4 files in any browser (tried both Firefox and Chrome on Windows and Linux), then only the audio is being played, but no video. I can, however, open the MP4 files in VLC player and that can play both video and audio without problem - so the files seem correct, just the browser cannot play them correctly.

Since I need to play the MP4 files in a browser, I need to extract both the video and the audio streams from the original files and create new MP4 files out of them, in a format so that the browser can play them. I also don't want to loose any frames during conversion - it would be OK to compress the video stream a bit, so that the resulting MP4 files would be a bit smaller than the originals, but the number of frames and the FPS value and these settings must be exactly as in the original file.

What would be the proper `ffmpeg` command to achieve this?
For your reference, this is the information from `ffprobe` on one of the videos:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ce62e37a00] Using non-standard frame rate 59/1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/winclients/ASFINAG/Abnahme/GX010005.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
    location        : +48.3743+016.2383/
    location-eng    : +48.3743+016.2383/
    firmware        : HD9.01.01.00.00
  Duration: 00:08:51.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60205 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59941 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
      timecode        : 15:35:51:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 15:35:51:04
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 15:35:51:04
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET
    Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 13 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-07T15:21:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I think you are seeing is that the videos are using H.265 codec and this is not well supported across browsers - current snapshot at time of writing: https://caniuse.com/hevc

You should not need to extract the tracks to transcode, however - ffmpeg will allow you specify the full input mp4 file and provide a new mp4 output file.

There is an ffmpeg wiki guide that goes into much more detail here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

At a high level you command will look something like:

> ffmpeg -i yourInputFile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac yourOutput.mp4

Look in particular the note on the CRF value in the guide linked to as this will affect the size and quality.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks.